# Git branch checkout says files would be overwritten alothough my working directory is clean

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout

I have the following branches 
`master -> php-merge-2016`, `master -> css-merge-2016` and `master -> css-merge-2016 -> b4-selector-removal`. To start with I need to `merge` `b4-selector-removal-new` to `php-merge-2016`.

Currently I am working on branch `b4-selector-removal` and all changes are committed and pushed to remove repository and `git status` shows **"working directory is clean"**

So to merge `b4-selector-removal-new` to `php-merge-2016` branches I first tried to be on my `php-merge-2016` branch. When I switch to `php-merge-2016` using `git checkout php-merge-2016` it gets checked out without a problem and here again `git status` shows **working directory is clean** as I haven't made any changes yet.

Just to do a bit of experiment I tried to switch back to `b4-selector-removal-new` branch without doing anything. But git is now saying:

> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>       sites/all/themes/base/css/info-grid.css
>       sites/all/themes/base/css/info-grid.css.map
>       sites/all/themes/desktop/css/print.css
>       sites/all/themes/desktop/css/print.css.map
>       sites/all/themes/mobile/css/ifa-upload.css
>       sites/all/themes/mobile/css/ifa-upload.css.map
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>   Aborting

Interesting thing is the files shown above are the ones which I committed and pushed last before switching back and forth between two mentioned branches.

Why I am getting this error? What is the work around. I did not use `git checkout -f` because I am not sure what it would do. I am not yet very much familiar with `git` yet so worrying using anything which forces something.

I had seen in another post that I could have used `git reset --hard` before checking out to another branch. what this do? Would this be harmless if I use this in my case? Will it resolve the issue?

Please help!

Comment: Are you a Windows user?  Tell me about your line endings.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: `git status` shows "clean working dir" when files are ignored. What is your `.gitignore`? You can also verify with [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Answer (score 0):

Create backup. Try `git reset --hard`

If that did not help, read this [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree)

Probably you manually set assume-unchanged or skip-worktree for you files.
In that case, changes are not affected in git status.